# Issue with Email Synchronization from Roundcube Webmail to Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, webmail, roundcube

I'm currently in the process of synchronizing emails from Roundcube webmail to Outlook. However, I've encountered a challenge: while Roundcube's inbox displays over 1500 emails, the synchronization to Outlook only results in 26 emails being retrieved. I'm seeking assistance to address this issue and ensure that all the emails are accurately synchronized between the two platforms.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing emails from Roundcube to Outlook can be resolve by having the correct configuration settings.

You can get this configuration settings from our email hosting provider so instead of using a default (mail.example.com) incoming and outgoing server, ask your email hosting provider for the direct server name.

In most cases, it's usually the same with your MX record  however this differs from provider to provider.

Once you have the incoming and outgoing mail server from your email provider, you should have the following information which you can use in Outlook settings:

- Username: *complete email address*
- Password: *your email address password*
- Incoming server: *(information provided by your email provider)*
- IMAP Port: 993
- SPA: OFF
- Outgoing server: *(information provided by your email provider)*
- SMTP Port: 465
- SPA: OFF
- Outgoing requires authentication

I hope this helps!

Comment: I hope that you find this answer helpful. Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you.